# Azure Functions 1.0.7 giving Could not load file or assembly error with EF Core 2

Tags: azure, entity-framework-core, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to move some functionality to Azure Functions. Created a project for EF Core 2 code, and referenced it to the Azure Functions project. Added the EF Core+SQLServer nugget packages to the Azure Functions project. When the function attempts to execute, this is the errors in the screen. I can see that the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore assembly is in the same directory as our azure functions dll.

Can anyone shed some light on why it's not finding it and how to fix this?

```
[1/3/2018 6:49:56 AM] A ScriptHost error has occurred
[1/3/2018 6:49:56 AM] Exception while executing function: Accounting. AS.Jobs: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. Could not find or load a specific file. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131621). System.Private.CoreLib: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
[1/3/2018 6:49:56 AM] Exception while executing function: Accounting
[1/3/2018 6:49:56 AM] Exception while executing function: Accounting. AS.Jobs: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. Could not find or load a specific file. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131621). System.Private.CoreLib: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
[1/3/2018 6:49:56 AM] Function completed (Failure, Id=56ba500b-7c3a-45c1-a9eb-8be4d52d1592, Duration=159ms)
[1/3/2018 6:49:56 AM]
[1/3/2018 6:49:56 AM] Executed 'Accounting' (Failed, Id=56ba500b-7c3a-45c1-a9eb-8be4d52d1592)
[1/3/2018 6:49:56 AM] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Accounting. AS.Jobs: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. Could not find or load a specific file. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131621). System.Private.CoreLib: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
[1/3/2018 6:49:56 AM]   Function had errors. See Azure WebJobs SDK dashboard for details. Instance ID is '56ba500b-7c3a-45c1-a9eb-8be4d52d1592'
[1/3/2018 6:49:56 AM] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Accounting. AS.Jobs: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. Could not find or load a specific file. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131621). System.Private.CoreLib: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
```

**Update: 1/3/2018**
I have VS 2017 15.5.2 installed, and I am building this in VS.

Here is the output of the function host when I run it from VS.

```
[1/4/2018 3:47:03 AM] Host configuration file read:
[1/4/2018 3:47:03 AM] {
[1/4/2018 3:47:03 AM] }
[1/4/2018 3:47:04 AM] Generating 1 job function(s)
[1/4/2018 3:47:04 AM] Starting Host (HostId=jlt03-962556955, Version=2.0.11353.0, ProcessId=21200, Debug=False, Attempt=0, FunctionsExtensionVersion=)
[1/4/2018 3:47:04 AM] Found the following functions:
[1/4/2018 3:47:04 AM] Jobs.Accounting.Run
[1/4/2018 3:47:04 AM]
Listening on http://localhost:7071/
```

Comment: Are you compiling .NET Standard 2.0 library and running on v2 (preview) version of Functions runtime?

Comment: I believe so, how do I tell for sure? All this multi platform stuff has made it a bit cumbersome.

Comment: Check `TargetFramework` in `csproj` and run `func -v` to see Runtime Version

Comment: TargetFramework is netstandard2.0 for the Azure Function project, and netstandard2.0;net462 for the EF Core 2 project. Where am I supposed to run func -v from?

Comment: I updated the question with more info, hope that can help. How should I reference my class assembly for EF Core? I have two different solutions for each project, and I am just pointing the Azure Function project to the output dir of the bin\release\netstandard2.0\{assembly} of the EF Core class.

Comment: I've even tried adding the EF Core 2.0.1 directly into the AF project and create a empty DBContext. It throws the exact same error before the function is even able to run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after much much more searching, I came across this [GitHub posted issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-cli/issues/335). It is the exact same issue that I am seeing here. Apparently it is a issue with Azure Functions 1.0.7 and EF Core 2.0.1.

I had to role back AF back to 1.0.6 **AND** I also had to role EF Core back to 2.0.0. Afterwards the function executed as expected.

I will be monitoring the GitHub issue and update this answer once it is confirmed to be fixed.

**Update**
This is now fixed with Azure Functions Core Tools 2.1.0 release.
https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/109

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me was to delete all folders under bin folder and build the app!!