# Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore Error in azure functions App

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-functions

I am using Visual Studio 2017 v-15.6.0 & AzureFunctions Project is Standard2.0 & webjobs 3.0.0-beta-3. i am trying to build deb context using entity framework core.
I am getting bellow error
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. Could not find or load a specific file. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131621)'

Please Help me to move forward.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wa07X.png)

Comment: You need to reference EF in all projects that will use it

Comment: I do have Ef reference in my azure function. still I am getting same  issue.

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of this question (which will help you resolve it): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48072879/azure-functions-1-0-7-giving-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-error-with-ef-core/48090553

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Azure Functions 1.0.7 giving Could not load file or assembly error with EF Core 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48072879/azure-functions-1-0-7-giving-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-error-with-ef-core)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using entity framework core 2.0.1. i downgraded to 2.0.0 its working fine. might be Azure Functions not supporting 2.0.0 above versions.